# Regular expresion for RegExp in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

I have the following in JavaScript:

```
function escape(text)
{
var tx = text.replace(/[&<>"']/g);
}
```

Im having problems trying to do the same on Dart:

```
var reg = new RegExp("/[&<>"']/g"); -->this throws error.
```

How can I get an equivalent expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape double quotes

```
new RegExp("/[&<>\"']", 'g');
```

Answer (score 4):

The Dart RegExp source does not use `/` to delimit regular expressions, they're just strings passed to the `RegExp` constructor.
It's usually recommended that you use a "raw string" because backslashes mean something in RegExps as well as in non-raw string literals, and the JavaScript RegExp `/\r\n/` would be `RegExp("\\r\\n")` in Dart without raw strings, but `RegExp(r"\r\n")` with a raw string, much more readable.
In this particular case, where the string contains both `'` and `"`, that becomes harder, but you can use a "multiline string" instead - it uses tripple quote characters as delimiters, so it can contain single quote characters unescaped (it doesn't have to actually span multiple lines).

Dart doesn't have something similar to the `g` flag of JavaScript regexps. Dart regexps are stateless, it's the functions using them which need to care about remembering where it matched, not the RegExp itself. So, no need for the `g`.

So:

```dart
RegExp(r"""[&<>"']""");
// or 
RegExp(r'''[&<>"']''');
```

That gets a little crowded with all those quotes, and you can choose to use a non-raw string instead so you can escape the quote which matches the string (which is easier because your RegExp does not contain any backslashes itself):

```dart
RegExp("[&<>\"']");
// or 
RegExp('[&<>"\']');
```

If you do that when your regexp uses a *RegExp* backslash, then you'll need to double the backslash, something which is easy to forget, which is why raw strings are recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer, I will definetly try it out.